# Rufus boot USB disk

Tags: rufus

I am using Windows 11 Home version. Wanted to create Boot disk using Rufus 4.2. It is asking for MS Dos or Freedos. I am confused. Which one to select? Their merit and demerits.

Comment: What OS do you want the disk to boot into? What will be the purpose of the disk?

Comment: Once the disk is booted, it will **NOT** have your familiar Windows OS, just the equivalent of CMD prompt: https://www.freedos.org/ or https://superuser.com/questions/1228136/what-version-of-ms-dos-does-rufus-use-to-make-bootable-usbs

Comment: Make sure you're using ISO as your file format to burn to USB and then stick to the recommended defaults and click start. That should work fine.